# What is the difference between [crewed-spaceflight] and [crewed-missions]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed that we have two tags that appear to be very closely related: [crewed-spaceflight](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crewed-spaceflight) (171 questions) and [crewed-missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crewed-missions) (23 questions). The question overlap between them is minimal; only [four questions are tagged with both](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crewed-spaceflight+crewed-missions).

The tag wiki don't really provide any guidance on the difference between the two. **crewed-spaceflight:**

> Crewed spaceflight (also referred to as human spaceflight or manned spaceflight) is space travel with a crew aboard the spacecraft. When a spacecraft is crewed, it can be operated directly, as opposed to being remotely operated or autonomous.

and **crewed-missions:**

> Use this tag for questions relating to missions that are manned by a crew.

What's the difference between the two? Which should I use when? Or should they be merged?

Comment: This question was inspired by my efforts at adding a tag about manned missions to [All this Mars talk: why bother?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17033/415)

Comment: Suggest it as a synonym, and I'll merge. I agree, they sound pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I don't have 5 score in either tag, so can't suggest a synonym. I do however suggest keeping crewed-spaceflight in that case because of its existing counterpart uncrewed-spaceflight, obsoleting crewed-missions. (I probably *could* go in and edit some of my older questions, but that seems like... cheating.)

Comment: While we're at it, [tag:extra-solar-flight] and [tag:interstellar-travel].....

Comment: I suggested they be synonyms, I await the decision of SESX overlords. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just went ahead and performed the merge. Thanks for keeping an eye out for this kind of stuff! Let us know if you see more!